# Is that possible to use style-loader and MiniExtractCssPlugin side by side in webpack bundling?

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader, css-modules

I'm currently creating components library with Webpack. I wan't my components library provides:

1. **React components**:
   It can be used as reusable React components that contain bundled javascript and CSS module
2. **CSS components**:
   It can be used in plain HTML nevertheless, via importing bundled CSS file

I'm using Webpack as build tools. **Is that possible to use style-loader and MiniExtractCssPlugin side by side in webpack bundling?** So that I can make every component's style is embeded in javascript bundle, and also providing bundled CSS file. Thanks!

Comment: have your tried to use `use: ['style-loader', MiniCss...]`?

Comment: I've tried that, resulting only extracted css (without inline css)

Comment: that stops on the minicss then. Split the css rule into two, one with style-loader, and the other one with minicss